# Low graphics performance of 1440p Monitor over HDMI

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I'm recently bought [Dell U2515H](http://www1.la.dell.com/vc/en/corp/peripherals/dell-u2515h-monitor/pd.aspx?refid=dell-u2515h-monitor&s=corp) monitor that I have connected with my [HP Pavilion 15 AU113TX](http://support.hp.com/za-en/product/hp-pavilion-15-au000-notebook-pc-series/10862158/document/c05239942) laptop using HDMI cable (Amazon Basics HDMI 2.0 cable), both, the Monitor as well as laptop, have HDMI 1.4 port. While the monitor supports full 1440p resolution, the video and graphics performance doesn't seem smooth.

I tried playing 1080p video file and I feel there's a slight stutter when it is playing from monitor, while the stutter is not present if I play it on laptop screen (1366x768 resolution). This lag is also noticed while simply scrolling webpage in Chrome, and certain OS animations.

Please note that my laptop has [Intel Core i5 7200U](https://ark.intel.com/products/95443/Intel-Core-i5-7200U-Processor-3M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz) (Kaby Lake) which actually supports 4k (@ 60 FPS) natively. Also, my laptop has 4 GB nVidia GeForce 940MX GPU.

I'm facing this slight stuttering on Windows 10 (which has even Dell Monitor drivers installed) and the stuttering is more noticeable on Ubuntu 16.10.

Here's the output of `xrandr` on Ubuntu while Monitor is connected with my laptop (with Monitor being primary display and laptop screen being secondary).

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3926 x 1440, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected 1366x768+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768      60.00*+  40.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
HDMI-1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 553mm x 311mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1200x960      59.99  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

How this can be fixed?

any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It could be due to the response time of the monitor, it's response time is only 19ms

Comment: Default response time of U2515H is 8ms, while switching to fast mode it is 6ms

Comment: This page says 19ms on/off -- 6ms gray-to-gray (http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/accessories/apd/210-ajiy?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&sku=210-AJIY)

Comment: Ok, but then if video performance is noticeably laggy then there must be something wrong, right? as I bought it after going through lot of reviews, and I saw people able to play some heavy games without any issues, while I'm just trying to play 1080p video file.